# Getting input from URL using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was given the following task:

define the route

GET /api/restaurants

This route must accept the numeric query parameters "page" and "perPage" as well as the string parameter "borough", ie: /api/restaurants?page=1&perPage=5&borough=Bronx.  It will use these values to return all "Restaurant" objects for a specific "page" to the client as well as optionally filtering by "borough", if provided.

my code is as follows

```
app.get('/api/restaurants/:page/:perPage/:borough', (req, res) =>{
  console.log("worked")
  console.log(req.params.page)
  console.log(req.params.perPage)
  console.log(req.params.borough) 
})
```

now here is the issue i m encountering, the route works fine if i enter the url in the following format

http://localhost:8000/api/restaurants/1/5/Bronx

however it doesn't work when using the format the instructor requires

http://localhost:8000/api/restaurants?page=1&perPage=5&borough=Bronx

I get "Cannot GET /api/restaurants", if anyone could please shed some light on what i m doing wrong i would appreciate it.

Comment: Well the pattern `/api/restaurants/:page/:perPage/:borough` does not match on `/api/restaurants`- You would need to explicitly specify a route for _that_ path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) and [query parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query). (They are not the same.)

You can access query parameters on `req.query`:

```js
app.get('/api/restaurants', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.page);
  console.log(req.query.perPage);
  console.log(req.query.borough);
});
```